# Accessing Angular components through service

Tags: angular

In an Angular application, I have a panel component that needs to retrieve some data from 3 non-sibling tree components. I could use a service to ask and return the information between them using Observables, but I tried an alternative way. Let me explain it with an example:

- From the panel component, I need to search in the 3 trees to locate an special node to make a call to the API with some properties of that node.
- To access the trees instantly from the panel, I've thought that I could use an existing shared service to store an array of references right after creating them.
- Now, I only have to get that array from the panel component to use the method provided by the trees to find nodes.

Some sample code:

**Sidebar.component.ts (The component that has the 3 trees)**

```js
// Get a list of the tree components
@ViewChildren(TreeComponent) treeComponents: QueryList<TreeComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Use the shared service to store the tree references globally
  this.sharedService.setTreeComponents(this.treeComponents.toArray());
}
```

**Shared.service.ts**

```js
private subjectTreeComponents = new BehaviorSubject<TreeComponent[]>(null);

setTreeComponents(trees: TreeComponent[]) {
  this.subjectTreeComponents.next(trees);
}

getActualTreeComponents(): TreeComponent[] {
  return this.subjectTreeComponents.getValue();
}
```

**Panel.component.ts**

```js
doAnApiCall() {
  // Get the tree components array from the global service
  let trees = this.sharedService.getActualTreeComponents();

  if(Array.isArray(trees)) {  // Security check
    trees.forEach(tree => {
      // I can call the tree component public methods from here
      let rootNode = tree.getRootNode();

      // Use root node and do find what we need to call the API etc...
    });
  }
}
```

This works, but I'm not 100% sure if it's a good practice to store references to components in a service to access them from anywhere. Is it OK? If not, what could be an alternative?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what you did there is basically hack your way through, a proper alternative would be to use a state-managment library, or a shared behavior subject on the service. you can google either of those, lots of info been written

Comment: Yes, I think that someday I'll have to integrate NgRx in the application, it's worth the time... Meanwhile I'll have a look at the shared behavior subjects you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to invoke component methods from within another component?

Comment: Hi! I always communicate components using a service but, in this particular case, the logic is a lot easier if I can get the data in this way...

Comment: Iam not exactly sure what the goal is, are `@ViewChildren(TreeComponent) treeComponents: QueryList<TreeComponent>;` angular components? It seems as if you're trying to call methods from those components from within `panel.component.ts`

Comment: Yes, `treeComponents` will hold a `QueryList` of my tree components, so I can use it to call their public methods (for example, the `getRootNode()` above).

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not best practice to get references to components through `@ViewChild`, pass them to a service and call their public methods from within another component.

The Problem is that you may get different results, or even worse, you may delete/rename the `getRootNode()` function in your tree components, but your `pipe.component.ts` is still trying to call it which will result in an error saying that it is not a function.

A more elegant (and safe) way is to use `Subject` and `Observable` to "ping" the other components to invoke their methods.

For Example:

Service:

```
  private _pingSource: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  public pingObservable: Observable<void> = this._pingSource.asObservable();
  public ping() {
    this._pingSource.next();
  }
```

Your "tree components":

```
constructor(private readonly _sharedService: SharedService){}
 public supscription: Subscription;
 this.subscription = this._sharedService.pingObservable.subscribe(
      () => // execute your method here e.g. this.getRootNode();
      });
```

dont forget to get rid of the subscription when the component is destroyed or you will generate a memory leak

```
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Panel Component:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // You can probably move this to ngOnInit() (?)
  this.sharedService.ping();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Once I run `getRootNode()` in the tree components, I would need to send it to `PanelComponent` to be processed using another Observable, which is what I want to avoid. Anyway, I agree with you that my solution is not the most elegant one...

Comment: Yup, pretty much what you will end up with. It is more code, but then again it isnt very complicated, whereas your solution is more error-prone.